# Quarto page specific body-width (and other properties)

Tags: quarto

I am new to Quarto and it helped me fast-track my website creation. I have, however, no experience with (s)css or web design.

I would like one of my pages (the landing page) to have a higher `body-width` than others. I expected that having the default in `_quarto.yml`

```
format:
  html:
    grid:
      body-width: 800px
```

.. and a specific one in the `index.qmd`

```
format:
  html:
    grid:
      body-width: 1000px
```

... would work, but it produces weird behaviour as [exactly described here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/6615#discussion-5557489) -- sometimes the other pages get wider when I navigate back and forth.

Can anyone help with this issue ? And tell me what is the recommended way to do page-specific layout changes ?